# Cannot get rid of "file name 'package"dart_file.dart' isn't a snake_case identifier" message

Tags: dart

I don't know if this is a dart problem or a VSCode Dart extension problem as I am new to dart programming.

1. I created a new Dart console project using VSCode.
2. I added the following line to the main dart file:

```
import 'package"dart_file.dart'
```

3. Note the " instead of :
4. When I tried to run this, I get the following comment:
   "The file name 'package"dart_file.dart' isn't a snake_case identifier."
5. I corrected this, replacing the " with : and putting in the correct path to the file. The program now runs.
6. The comment does not disappear. I have searched all of the files generated by the VSCode Dart extension but cannot find any reference to the 'package"dart_file.dart'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: The line is still not correct. It should be `import 'package:name_of_project_you_want_to_import_from/dart_file.dart';` . If you want to import from your own project, you need to use the name of your own project. If you don't know the project name, look inside `pubspec.yaml` for the name field.

Comment: @julemand101 You did not read what I wrote closely enough. The problem is not that I have not included the name_of_project... See step 5.

When I run:  dart run dart_project_name.dart  from the command line, the project builds with no errors/warnings/comments, and the comment in VSCode disappears. Therefore, I am assuming that the problem is in the VSCode Dart extension. I will move this discussion there.

Comment: Ah sorry. Can you try Ctrl+Shift+P and search+run the "Dart: Restart Analysis Server" command?

Answer (score 0):

snake_case is a variable naming convention where each word is in lower case, and separated by underscores and the advantage of snake case is that it makes variable names easy to read.

so you need to import classes like this exemple to get rid of the annoying comments:

```
import 'package:your_project_name/lib_or_folder/dart_file.dart';
```

after changing the name sometimes you need to close the IDE (vs code) and clean memory then open it again so the IDE can see the name's update.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file like if you have BookView.dart change it to book_view.dart

Comment: Make it more generic this way : use snake_case convention instead CamelCase